# TikZ Figure with text, arrows, dashed line, and brackets

Tags: arrows, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows, tikz-trees, tikz-cd

I am trying to produce the following figure: 
[image: Expected Figure]

So far, this is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{arydshln}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\centering

\[
\begin{array}{ccccc}
\text{First Factor} & \xrightarrow{\hspace*{2cm}} & \text{Second Factor} & \xrightarrow{\hspace*{2cm}} & \text{Multiple Factors} \\
\text{(Parenthetical)} & &  &  & \text{(M = 100)} \\
\end{array}
\]

\[
\begin{array}{ccccc}
&&& \left\downarrow\rule{0cm}{1cm}\right.\phantom{(\varphi^n)^*}\\
\end{array}
\]

Long text explaining what is the output in this row  \\ $Y_{ipt}$ = f(factor1, factor2, factor3, factor4, factor5, factor6, factor7, factor8)

\[
\begin{array}{ccccc}
&&& \left\downarrow\rule{0cm}{1cm}\right.\phantom{(\varphi^n)^*}\\
\end{array}
\]

Another Long text explaining what is the output in this row
$\hat{Y}_{pt}$ explaining the predicted values considering factor1, factor2, factor3, factor4, factor5, factor6, factor7,  and factor8

\[
\begin{array}{ccccc}
&&& \left\downarrow\rule{0cm}{1cm}\right.\phantom{(\varphi^n)^*}\\
\end{array}
\]

One more long text explaining the output \\\hdashline[10.5pt/7pt]

New stage begins calculating the mean ($\mu$) and the variance ($\omega$) with some other parameters to understand our results

\[
\begin{array}{ccccc}
&&& \left\downarrow\rule{0cm}{1cm}\right.\phantom{(\varphi^n)^*}\\
\end{array}
\]

$\mu_{pt} =$ f(factor1, factor2, factor3, factor4, factor5, factor6, factor7, factor8, factor1*factor2, factor2*factor3, factor4*factor5)
$\omega_{pt}$=f(factor9, factor10, factor11, factor12, factor13, factor14, factor15, factor16, factor17, factor18, factor19, factor20)

\end{document}
```

As you can see, I am far from it as what I am producing is neither efficient nor really a figure. I am sure there is a better way to do it using a package such as TikZ for example, but I can't code it successfully.

Comment: Yes this is quite easy to do with tikz. I'm not at a computer so cannot help right now. Start by learning to do the text nodes and arrows between them. There are many examples on this site, also Google "tikz examples"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With TikZ, as suggested @daleif in his comment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                decorations.pathmorphing,
                calligraphy,
                positioning}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{suspend join/.code={\def\tikz@after@path{}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\centering

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 12mm and 0mm,
  start chain = A going below,
every node/.append style = {align=flush center},
   box/.style = {minimum height=9mm, text width=124mm,
                 font=\itshape\sffamily\small, on chain=A, join=by arr},
   arr/.style = {-{Triangle[angle=60:2 3]}, thick},
    BC/.style = {decorate,  % Brace, calligraphy
                 decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=4pt,
                             pre =moveto, pre  length=1pt,
                             post=moveto, post length=1pt,
                             raise=4pt,
                             mirror}, % for mirroring of brace
                 very thick,
                 pen colour=black
                },
                        ]
\node[box] {};
\node (A-1C) at (A-1) {Second Factor};
\node (A-1L) [right=of A-1.west] {First Factor\\(Parenthetical)};
\node (A-1R) [ left=of A-1.east] {Multipole Factor\\($M=100$)};
\draw[arr]  (A-1L) -- (A-1C);
\draw[arr]  (A-1C) -- (A-1R);
\draw   (A-1.north west) -- (A-1.north east);

\node[box]  {Long text explaining what is the output in this row
             $Y_{ipt}=f$ factor1, factor2, factor3, factor4,
             factor5, factor6, factor7,  and factor8};
\node[box]  {Another Long text explaining what is the output in this row
             $\hat{Y}_{pt}$ explaining the predicted values considering factor1, factor2, factor3, factor4,\\
             factor5, factor6, factor7,  and factor8};
\node[box]  {One more long text explaining the output};

\draw[dashed]   (A-4.south west) -- (A-4.south east);

\node[box, suspend join,
      below=0pt of A-4]  
            {New stage begins calculating the mean ($\mu$) and the variance ($\omega$) with some other parameters to understand our results};
\node[box]  {New stage begins calculating the mean ($\mu$) and the variance ($\omega$) with some other parameters to understand our results};

\node[box]  {$\mu_{pt} =$ f(factor1, factor2, factor3, factor4, factor5, factor6, factor7, factor8,\\
                factor1*factor2, factor2*factor3, factor4*factor5)\\
            $\omega_{pt}=f$(factor9, factor10, factor11, factor12, factor13, factor14, factor15, factor16,\\ 
                factor17, factor18, factor19, factor20)};
\draw   (A-7.south west) -- (A-7.south east);
%%%%
\draw[BC] (A-1.north west) -- 
    node[left=8pt] {\textbf{1\textsuperscript{st}}\\ \textbf{stage}} (A-4.south west);
\draw[BC] (A-5.north west) -- 
    node[left=8pt] {\textbf{2\textsuperscript{st}}\\ \textbf{stage}} (A-7.south west);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @daleif, thank you very much. `\textbf` is now corrected.